# Delete records from Multiple Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on e commerce project. I have a scenario as below.

There is a master table and a stored procedure. After inserting the data into `Master` table I am executing that stored procedure. It will be creating multiple tables.

Now I would like to delete a record from `Master` table. Corresponding tables should be deleted from database.

Can you please guide me in writing the query for the above scenario?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using database triggers? see the [docs on the subject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

You will need to create a delete trigger on the `Master` table.  This trigger will be run when a record is deleted; and as such you can execute some SQL to drop the required tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MasterTableRowDeleted
    ON MasterDatabase.dbo.MasterTable
    FOR DELETE5
AS
    DROP TABLE SlaveDatabase.dbo.SlaveTable001
GO
```